# NSLinguisticTaggerOptions in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nslinguistictagger

Is this a bug in swift ? or am i missing something here i have declared the following
`let opts = (NSLinguisticTaggerOptions.OmitWhitespace | NSLinguisticTaggerOptions.JoinNames)`

i get the following error 
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
Playground execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

*update*
if i inline the option in to the calling method, it seems to work

```
 let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes:NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemesForLanguage("en"), options: 3)

tagger.string = someString
    //if i inline the options it seems to work
    tagger.enumerateTagsInRange(r, scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass, options:(NSLinguisticTaggerOptions.OmitWhitespace | NSLinguisticTaggerOptions.JoinNames)){
            tag,range,_,_ in
            let token = nsstr.substringWithRange(range)
            println("\(tag), \(token)")

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `options` parameter, try `Int(opts.toRaw())`.

(The "3" that you tried worked because it is the raw version.)